# JavaFX - How to Get Editor Text from ComboBoxTableCell

Tags: java, javafx

My table contains a `ComboBoxTableCell` with `setComboBoxEditable(true)`. I need to obtain the text typed into the editor of the combo box.

A regular ComboBox contains `getEditor().getText()` method to achieve this. But how can I achieve this in `ComboBoxTableCell` since it's lacking `getEditor()`?

Comment: Just a guess here, but it seems like there is a `setOnEditCommit` event handler that you can use. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860019/javafx-create-combobox-tablecell) example.

Comment: i am working on auto-complete filtering. i need to get text as it's typed, not when it's committed

Comment: Well, you talked about `getText()` which doesn't get content as it is typed. That's why I suggested what I suggested.

Comment: `setOnEditCommit` fires when you press enter. i need to filter results before pressing enter or clicking away

Comment: This could be duplicate -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885092/how-to-get-values-selected-in-comboboxtablecell-in-table-view

Comment: Sounds like he wants an `onKeyleased` or some binding situation.

Comment: no its not a duplicate. i dont need `setOnEditCommit`. its not what im looking for. i need to get typed text of the combobox. i could use `setOnKeyReleased` to build a string based on each character typed, but thats not elegant

Comment: what's the problem with getting the textfield of the  editable combo? grab it and either listen to its textProperty or use a textFormatter

Comment: how do i get the textfield of the editable combo if i dont have access to the combo object?

Comment: subclass and grab the cell's graphic (that's the combo) in the very first startEdit

Comment: yeah i ended up creating a custom `TableCell` with a `ComboBox`